# Navigation bar missing in storyboard with show segue in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

Why can't I see the navigation item under my second View Controller? My setup is as follows: I have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller. This view controller is linked to a second view controller with a "Show" segue. I can select & edit the navigation bar for the first view controller, but cannot see it in the element list for the second view controller. I also cannot edit it in the second view controller (i.e. add a button). How can I fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**, **drag** a navigation item under your second view controller:
[image]

**Then**, you have it to edit:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How can you link the firstViewController and secondViewController?  I try to link and I only can link the firstViewController and secondViewController in there. [image]

But, this link is error, I set the different color for two viewController, the secondViewController cannot display.

Answer (score 0):

So, you lost Navigation Bar? Select the View Controller you want to add and click on Status Bar / Top Bar dropdown list in Attributes
 Inspector. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug on Xcode, you can manually drag a Navigation Bar to your Second ViewController.